# Нужны подробности о предоставлении "кредита" при создании бесплатной учетной записи Azure

Tags: azure

Учебник по программированию предлагает создать базу данных Azure. Я перехожу на https://portal.azure.com/ и в разделе создания бесплатной учетной записи для создания базы данных читаю: "Вы можете исследовать Azure с кредитом в 200 долл. США в течение 30 дней, ..". Этот кредит я кому-то должен буду отдавать? Или это "условные" деньги для использования на сайте, например, для покупки продуктов Microsoft? Может это глупый вопрос, но тем не менее.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Да, грубо говоря вам дают $200 на 30 дней, которые вы можете потратить на ресурсы в Ажуре. Как только время истечет или закончатся деньги, вам отключат сервисы, если вы не перейдете на платную подписку. $200 не так уж много в масштабах облака, но для тестирования хватит.

Для обучения данный вариант идеальный.

Я бы еще порекомендовала следующий вариант для тестирования - "песочницу" на сайте обучения ажуром.

Здесь: https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/learn/azure/

У них огромный выбор бесплатных курсов и при выполнение вам дают временный доступ к ресурсам для их выполнения.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

Да, это виртуальные деньги, которые предназначены для тестирования сервисов. Деньги закончатся, нужно будет переходить на платный тариф или забыть про эту подписку )) https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/free/

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]